# How to strip decorations (text properties) from a string?

Tags: string, text-properties

By a "decorated string" I mean something like

```
#("foo" 0 4 (fontified t face font-lock-function-name-face))
```

...as opposed to the "plain string"

```
"foo"
```

(If Elisp code reads a string directly from a buffer, it may be decorated like this.)

What's the simplest way to convert a decorated string to a plain one (by stripping all the decorations)?

Comment: substring-no-properties

Comment: Why do you need these properties removed ? They usually do no harm. Just pretend they don't exist might be a good enough solution.

Comment: @YoungFrog I e.g. ran into a problem with passing urls as text properties to eww.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Your propertized string looks wrong - perhaps you copied it wrong.  `foo` has only 3 characters, so it is impossible for it to be fontified on chars 0 to 4 (i.e., chars 0, 1, 2, and 3 - that's 4 chars).  I use 3 instead of 4 in the example here.]

```
(let* ((foo    #("foo" 0 3 (fontified t face font-lock-function-name-face)))
       (start  0)
       (end    (length foo)))
  (set-text-properties start end nil foo)
  foo)
```

> `set-text-properties` is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(set-text-properties START END PROPERTIES &optional OBJECT)`
>
> Completely replace properties of text from `START` to `END`.
>
> The third argument `PROPERTIES` is the new property list.
>
> If the optional fourth argument `OBJECT` is a buffer (or nil, which means
>   the current buffer), `START` and `END` are buffer positions (integers or
>   markers).  If `OBJECT` is a string, `START` and `END` are 0-based indices into it.
>   If `PROPERTIES` is nil, the effect is to remove all properties from
>   the designated part of OBJECT.

See the Elisp manual, node [Changing Properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html).  There you will see this, under function `remove-text-properties` (which you could also use to do the job):

> To remove **all** text properties from certain text, use `set-text-properties` and specify `nil` for the new property list.

---

As @Dan mentioned, you can also use `substring-no-properties`, but be aware that it returns a new string.  It does not modify the actual string object that you pass it.  Both `remove-text-properties` and `set-text-properties` change the string you pass them.

For example:

```
(setq foo #("foo" 0 3 (fontified t face font-lock-function-name-face)))
(setq bar foo)
(set-text-properties 0 (length foo) nil foo)
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are now just `"foo"`, with no properties.

But:

```
(setq foo #("foo" 0 3 (fontified t face font-lock-function-name-face)))
(setq bar foo)
(setq foo (substring-no-properties foo))
```

Now `foo` has no properties but `bar` still has them.